# Reading and writing to the file Android

Tags: android

I am learning Android and I am making some basic math program(game). It gets two random numbers, random operator, and 30 secs to solve math problems as much as you can. If you solve problem u get 1 point.

Anyway right now, I want to get number of points that user have made, and write it to the file, and later to read it ( for now just to log it).

When I click to button to write file, it does and I get this log message:
09-21 21:11:45.424: DEBUG/Writing(778): This is writing log: 2

Yeah, seems that it writes. Okey, lets read it.

09-21 21:11:56.134: DEBUG/Reading log(778): This is reading log:2

It reads it.

But when I try again to write, it seems that it will overwrite previous data.

09-21 21:17:19.183: DEBUG/Writing(778): This is writing log: 1
09-21 21:17:28.334: DEBUG/Reading log(778): This is reading log:1

As you can see it reads just last input.

Here it is that part of code, where I am writing and reading it.

```
public void zapisi() {
    // WRITING
    String eol = System.getProperty("line.separator");
    try {
        FileOutputStream fOut = openFileOutput("samplefile.txt",
                MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
        OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(fOut);

        osw.write(poenibrojanje+eol);
        //for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
        Log.d("Writing","This is writing log: "+poenibrojanje);
        //}

        //osw.flush();
        osw.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}


private void citaj() {

    // READING

    String eol = System.getProperty("line.separator");
    try {
        BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                openFileInput("samplefile.txt")));
        String line;
        StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
        while ((line = input.readLine()) != null) {
            buffer.append(line + eol);
        }
        //TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.result);
        Log.d("Reading log","This is reading log:"+buffer);
        System.out.println(buffer);
        //tvRezultat.setText(buffer.toString());

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the openFileOutput ("samplefile.txt", MODE_APPEND)

Comment: Can you explain a little better? When I try this :                       FileOutputStream fOut = openFileOutput("samplefile.txt",true
     MODE_WORLD_READABLE)        I get this error:  The method openFileOutput(String, int) in the type ContextWrapper is not applicable for the arguments (String, boolean)         ;

Comment: Oh, ffs now I get this error when I tried to read it, or write:09-21 21:46:19.185: WARN/System.err(832): java.io.FileNotFoundException: /samplefile.txt

Comment: Perhaps something is wrong with your file path. Where did you save the file?

Comment: Thank you very much, it works with openFileOutput ("samplefile.txt", MODE_APPEND).

Comment: Hmm yes with the first way you have to specify the absolute file path, with the second you don't, because openFileOutput points inside the Context's application package. I will remove the first solution in order to prevent any misunderstanding.